# JProgressBar does not fill all the way

Tags: java, swing, swingworker, jprogressbar

I have a `JProgressBar` which I have set the maximum value to 150. With a `javax.swing.Timer`, I update the progress bar and increase the `time` variable by 1. The issue is that once `time` reaches 100, the progress bar will not update any more and remains in the position shown below:

[image: JProgressBar 2/3 filled]

Why does this occur? Is there any way to fix the problem?

```
public class Test {
    int time = 0, duration = 150;
    JProgressBar progressBar;
    Timer timer;

    public Test() {
        GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(layout);
        constraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        timer = new Timer(98, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                time++;

                if (time == duration) {
                    time = 0;
                    timer.stop();
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();

        progressBar = new JProgressBar(0,duration);
        progressBar.setValue(0);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(false);
        layout.setConstraints(progressBar,constraints);
        frame.add(progressBar);


        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        ProgressBarUpdater pbUpdater = new ProgressBarUpdater();
        pbUpdater.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent ev) {
                progressBar.setValue(time);
            }
        });
        pbUpdater.execute();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public class ProgressBarUpdater extends SwingWorker<Void,Void> {
        @Override
        public Void doInBackground() {
            setProgress(0);
            while (time <= duration)
                setProgress(Math.min(time,duration));
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what Timer class do you use, and what does the 98 mean? Maybe that the action should only be invoked 98 times? The class `java.util.Timer` does not have such a constructor as you used, so which class did you use?

Comment: @cello `javax.swing.Timer`, which has a constructor that takes an `int` parameter specifying the delay in milliseconds, and an `ActionListener` paramenter.

Comment: oh, forgot about that one. thx!

Comment: Why not just use the Timer to update the progress bar directly?

Comment: @Reimeus How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `setProgress()` in the worker is on scale 0 to 100.

Do this change and it will work as expected:

```
public class ProgressBarUpdater extends SwingWorker<Void,Void> {
    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() {
        setProgress(0);
        while (time <= duration)
            setProgress((Math.min(time,duration) * 100) / duration); // convert to percent
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not quite what I was looking for. I had done this initially, but wanted the progress bar to update the number of times that `duration` was equal to (for instance, every 98 milliseconds the progress bar would fill in 1/150th of the way). Is there any way to change the scale?

Comment: I am afraid not. If you kindly look here, you'll see the value is integer, so you cannot get more fine-grained values. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#setProgress(int)

Comment: Oh well. Thanks for trying to help, at least. :)